# android how to run a program inside a fragment in other program

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragments

I want to know how I can run another Android application inside my own existing Android application as an activity or a fragment or any other way.

Example: if I want to open a text file and be able to edit it using an android text editor program and utilize that editors features.

I want to know if it possible or not and if it is how can I implement this

Thanks!

Comment: `i want to know if it possible or not` **NO**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot include an app within your own app. (If I read your question correctly, you want to do in Android what **iframe** does for **HTML**).

Your options are to either *find a good text editor library* to include in your project, or open another app via Intent.

Comment: like you are in my mind 
exactly i want it like iframe in html

Answer (score 2):

there is no such this as running another program inside your program. when you open a text editor program you leave your app so no you cannot run another program, let alone inside a fragment